# Adding Additional packages to Anaconda Installer

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda, miniconda

I am curious to know if there are methods where I can add additional packages to the anaconda installer. I am basically looking for a solution for creating an anaconda installer which has some extra python packages added along with it. Thus the participants to whom I give the installer need not be worrying about Internet connectivity or to add additional commands.

This is meant for an introductory hands-on python session. Hence the objective is to make the whole installation process less confusing as possible to the participants of the session.

I am aware of using docker as well as using environments. I am looking for something more simpler, say as seamless as anaconda installation for my participants.

Currently, I am thinking of doing the following.

1) Provide the `.tar.gz` file of the packages along with the installer

2) After installation and creating environments, install the libraries using `pip` from the `.tar.gz`
`python -m pip install c:\mymodule\great.tar.gz`

Any method which is simpler than the above one is welcome.

Comment: If you are planning to distribute conda package tarballs, you will not be able to use pip to install them, rather you have to use conda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `conda` documentation on [creating custom channels](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html):

> If you do not wish to upload your packages to the Internet, you can
>   build a custom repository served either through a web server or
>   locally using a `file://` URL.

The instructions on that page tell you how to create a local custom repository from conda packages. They're aimed at people who are building their own packages but as far as I can see you can also use the existing packages that you can download from the repositories at https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/.

You can then use the `file://` URL of that repository in the `-c` specification of `conda create` and/or `conda install` commands to set up the environment for your users to work in.